# How to search in IMAP mail subject for non-ascii text

Tags: perl, search, substring, imap

Here is the MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IMAP::Client;
use Encode qw/decode/;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $user = 'my-user@gmail.com';
my $pwd = 'secret';

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
    server          => 'imap.gmail.com',
    user            => $user,
    pass            => $pwd,
    ssl             => 1,      # (use SSL? default no)
    ssl_verify_peer => 1,      # (use ca to verify server, default yes)
    port            => 993
) or die "Could not connect to IMAP server: $!";

$imap->login or die('Login failed: ' . $imap->last_error);

# all the incoices from my telephone company
$imap->select('INBOX');
my $messages = $imap->search({
    from    => 'invoice@mgts.ru',
    #subject => '2020',
});

unless(defined($messages))
{
    $imap->logout();
    die "no messages";
}

foreach my $id (@$messages)
{
    my $summary = $imap->get_summaries([$id])->[0];

    my $subject = $summary->subject;
    $subject = decode('MIME-Header', $subject);
    print $subject."\n";
}
```

This outputs all the invoices from `invoice@mgts.ru` in the mailbox:

```
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Июнь 2017 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Июль 2017 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Август 2017 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Ноябрь 2017 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Декабрь 2017 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Ноябрь 2018 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Декабрь 2018 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Декабрь 2019 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Март 2020 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Апрель 2020 г.
```

Everything is correct.

Now I add the new condition, uncommenting:

```
#subject => '2020',
```

And I get all the invoices from 2020:

```
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Март 2020 г.
Счёт за услуги ПАО МГТС за Апрель 2020 г.
```

But when I add the word "Апрель" (April) to the search:

```
subject => 'Апрель 2020',
```

I get "no messages", despite the fact, that this substring exists in the subject of 1 email in the mailbox.

Subject in the email looks like this:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=D0=A1=D1=87=D1=91=D1=82=20?=
```

What's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried `subject => encode_utf8('Апрель 2020')` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, it didn't help.

Comment: What happens if you skip `2020`? I.e. `subject => 'Апрель'`

Comment: "subject => 'Апрель'" - no messages.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Maybe, the charset of subject is not UTF-8, but a 1 byte Russian charset like cp1251?

Comment: @HåkonHægland No, it's utf-8: "Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=D0=A1=D1=87=D1=91=D1=82=20?=
"

Comment: Seems to be the same problem with [Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail)

Comment: @HåkonHægland They are probably using the same underlying code. No idea what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It seems like `Net::IMAP::Client` doesn't support [IMAP4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) that covers UTF-8 encoded strings.
2. According to Gmail documentation, you can use [X-GM-RAW](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw) attribute to fetch the same result of Gmail web interface.

If I must use `Net::IMAP::Client`, I would add a new method to perform `X-GM-RAW`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IMAP::Client;
use Encode qw/decode/;
use IO::Socket qw(:crlf);
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $user = 'my-user@gmail.com';
my $pwd = 'secret';

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
    server          => 'imap.gmail.com',
    user            => $user,
    pass            => $pwd,
    ssl             => 1,      # (use SSL? default no)
    ssl_verify_peer => 1,      # (use ca to verify server, default yes)
    port            => 993
) or die "Could not connect to IMAP server: $!";

$imap->login or die('Login failed: ' . $imap->last_error);

# Add search_gmail method to Net::IMAP::Client
sub Net::IMAP::Client::search_gmail {
    my ($self, $criteria) = @_;

    my @crit;
    for my $key (keys %{$criteria}) {
        push @crit, join ":", $key, $criteria->{$key};
    }

    my $crit_str = join q{ }, @crit;

    my ($ok, $lines);
    ($ok, $lines) = $self->_tell_imap('SEARCH' => "CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW " . do {
        use bytes;
        sprintf qq{{%d}%s%s}, length($crit_str), $CRLF, $crit_str;
    });

    return unless $ok;

    for my $line (@{$lines->[1]}) {
        if ($line =~ s/^\*\s+SEARCH\s+//ig) {
            $line =~ s/\s*$//g;
            return [ map { $_ + 0 } split(/\s+/, $line) ];
        }
    }
}

# all the incoices from my telephone company
$imap->select('INBOX');
my $messages = $imap->search_gmail({
    from    => 'invoice@mgts.ru',
    #subject => '2020',
});

unless(defined($messages))
{
    $imap->logout();
    die "no messages";
}

foreach my $id (@$messages)
{
    my $summary = $imap->get_summaries([$id])->[0];

    my $subject = $summary->subject;
    $subject = decode('MIME-Header', $subject);
    print $subject."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(See at the bottom of this post for a Python example that seems to work)

I tried another module [Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail) since it has an option for `debug` output (I first sent an email to myself with subject `Апрель 2020` such that I could test the behavior easily):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail;
use Encode qw(encode_utf8);

my $server = 'imap.gmail.com';
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail->new($server, debug => 1);
my $user = 'me@gmail.com';
my $pass = 'mypass';

if(!$imap->login($user,$pass)){
    die "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
}
my $num_messages = $imap->select('INBOX') or die $imap->errstr;
my @ids = $imap->search(encode_utf8('SUBJECT "Апрель 2020"'));
say "Found ", (scalar @ids), " messages";
```

**Output**:

```
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 133 in sub _connect] connecting to imap.gmail.com:993
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 133 in sub _connect] connected, returning socket
[./p.pl line 11 in sub new] waiting for socket ready
[./p.pl line 11 in sub new] looking for greeting
[./p.pl line 11 in sub new] got a greeting: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 51.174.5.83 u18mb43700719ljl\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1252 in sub _send_cmd] 0 LOGIN me@gmail.com "mypass"\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 265 in sub _process_cmd] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 265 in sub _process_cmd] 0 OK hakon.hagland@gmail.com authenticated (Success)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] 0 OK hakon.hagland@gmail.com authenticated (Success)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1252 in sub _send_cmd] 1 SELECT "INBOX"\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MailFlagBit0 $MailFlagBit1 $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing NotJunk)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MailFlagBit0 $MailFlagBit1 $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing NotJunk)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MailFlagBit0 $MailFlagBit1 $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing NotJunk \*)] Flags permitted.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MailFlagBit0 $MailFlagBit1 $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing NotJunk \*)] Flags permitted.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 638142060] UIDs valid.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 638142060] UIDs valid.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * 27869 EXISTS\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * 27869 EXISTS\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * 0 RECENT\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * 0 RECENT\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * OK [UIDNEXT 32724] Predicted next UID.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * OK [UIDNEXT 32724] Predicted next UID.\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4375397]\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4375397]\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 413 in sub _process_cmd] 1 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] 1 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1252 in sub _send_cmd] 2 SEARCH SUBJECT "Апрель 2020"\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 615 in sub _process_cmd] 2 BAD Could not parse command\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] 2 BAD Could not parse command\r\n
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1192 in sub _seterrstr] Could not parse command\r
Found 0 messages
```

Notice the output:

```
[...l/5.30.0/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 1277 in sub _cmd_ok] 2 BAD Could not parse command\r\n
```

This is the socket returning `2 BAD Could not parse command` at [line 1260](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-IMAP-Simple/source/lib/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm#L1260)

---

Similarly, using the Python [IMAPClient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/) module:

```
user = 'me@gmail.com';
passw = "mypass";
from imapclient import IMAPClient
server = IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', use_uid=True, ssl=True)
result = server.login(user, passw)
print(result)
select_info = server.select_folder('INBOX')
print(select_info)
messages = server.search(['SUBJECT', 'Апрель 2020'.encode('utf8')])
print(messages)
```

Gives output:

```
b'me@gmail.com authenticated (Success)'
{b'PERMANENTFLAGS': (b'\\Answered', b'\\Flagged', b'\\Draft', b'\\Deleted', b'\\Seen', b'$MailFlagBit0', b'$MailFlagBit1', b'$NotJunk', b'$NotPhishing', b'$Phishing', b'NotJunk', b'\\*'), b'FLAGS': (b'\\Answered', b'\\Flagged', b'\\Draft', b'\\Deleted', b'\\Seen', b'$MailFlagBit0', b'$MailFlagBit1', b'$NotJunk', b'$NotPhishing', b'$Phishing', b'NotJunk'), b'UIDVALIDITY': 638142060, b'EXISTS': 27869, b'RECENT': 0, b'UIDNEXT': 32724, b'HIGHESTMODSEQ': 4375417, b'READ-WRITE': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 982, in _search
    data = self._raw_command_untagged(b'SEARCH', args)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 1445, in _raw_command_untagged
    typ, data = self._raw_command(command, args, uid=uid)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 1507, in _raw_command
    return self._imap._command_complete(to_unicode(command), tag)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 1027, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 11, in <module>
    messages = server.search(['SUBJECT', 'Апрель 2020'.encode('utf8')])
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 956, in search
    return self._search(criteria, charset)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 995, in _search
    criteria='"%s"' % criteria if not isinstance(criteria, list) else criteria
imapclient.exceptions.InvalidCriteriaError: b'Could not parse command'

This error may have been caused by a syntax error in the criteria: ['SUBJECT', b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c 2020']
Please refer to the documentation for more information about search criteria syntax..
https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/#imapclient.IMAPClient.search
```

---

Finally I found [a Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612617/2173773) that actually seems to work:

```
import imaplib
user = "me@gmail.com"
passw = "mypass";
sock = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
sock.login(user, passw)
sock.select()
sock.debug = 4
sock.literal = u"Апрель 2020".encode('utf8')
res = sock.uid('SEARCH', 'CHARSET', 'UTF-8', 'SUBJECT')
print(res)
```

**Output**:

```
  04:44.46 > b'DMOM3 UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 SUBJECT {17}'
  04:44.52 < b'+ go ahead'
  04:44.52 write literal size 17
  04:44.67 < b'* SEARCH 32720'
  04:44.67 < b'DMOM3 OK SEARCH completed (Success)'
('OK', [b'32720'])
```

Comment: Sad that Perl can't handle it, Perl is good at Unicode, but it's syntax is a bit _exotic_ even if I like Perl

Comment: For information, `ль` is `U+43B . U+44C`, maybe a hint ?

Comment: It's not that Perl the language can't handle it, but that some module can't.

Answer (score -1):

What I would start treating Unicode:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use utf8;
binmode $_, ":utf8" for qw/STDOUT STDIN STDERR/;
```

With recent Perl:

```
use feature 'unicode_strings';
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Important-Caveats

Comment: No, still no messages. Can you try with your mailbox?

Comment: Yes, tried with and without `binmode $_, ":utf8" for qw/STDOUT STDIN STDERR/;`.

Comment: It's definitely Unicode, cause my own email with "April 2020" is being searched correctly.

Comment: No, sorry, just playing for myself.

Comment: 2) The OP is already doing better than `binmode $_, ":utf8" for qw/STDOUT STDIN STDERR/;` by doing `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`  (Don't use `:utf8`!)

Comment: 3) `use feature 'unicode_strings';` has no effect on the code in question. It fixes a bug in certain operators (e.g. `lc`, `m//`), none of which are used here.