# Searching for UTF-8 encoded subjects with imaplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I have some working code to fetch mail bodies and I want to filter the subject with a non-ascii string. Other forums suggest using the `.uid` class to do so, but the behavior is not logic to me.

**Current code:**

```
import imaplib
import email

username = secret
password = secret

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")

status, messages = imap.select("INBOX",readonly=True)

res, msg = imap.search(None, 'HEADER Subject "string to be encoded with UTF-8"')
```

**Suggested code:**

```
import imaplib
import email

username = secret
password = secret

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")

status, messages = imap.select("INBOX",readonly=True)

imap.literal = u"string to be encoded with UTF-8".encode('utf-8')
res, msg = imap.uid('SEARCH', 'CHARSET', 'UTF-8', 'SUBJECT')
```

The [suggested code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997928/python-imap-search-using-a-subject-encoded-with-utf-8) works fine, but the returned array (`msg[0]`) contains indicies of the mailbox that are out of bounds. On the contrary when I use the `.search` class, valid indices are returned instead as long as I search for ASCII strings (both UTF-8 and non-UTF-8 encoded strings aren't accepted here). I don't quite understand the behaviour and logic of `.uid` because of this. I'd be grateful if someone can help me on the way.

How can I filter the subject with a UTF-8 string?

Comment: The only difference between 'search' and 'mid search' are whether it returns Message Sequence Numbers (MSNs, numbered 1-N, n being the number of mails in your mail box) or Unique Identifiers (UIDs, numbered increasing, numbers generally never reused, even if messages are deleted).  UIDs are more stable, and it's recommended to use them for everything: `x.fetch(...)` -> `x.uid('FETCH', ... )`, `x.search(...) ` -> `x.uid('SEARCH', ...)`, etc.

Comment: I managed to solve the scenario with the following:

`res, msg = imap.uid('search', None, 'HEADER Subject "Subject to filter"')`
`messages = msg[0].decode('utf-8').split()`
`for uid in messages: `
`    res, msg = imap.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)') `
`    #parsing logic to follow `


Thanks for your effort and suggestion to use UID instead. It is stated on the imaplib pages that `.uid` is recommended.

Comment: Try to use high level lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Vladimir, I will give this a shot in my next project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the scenario with the following, using the recommended way with `.uid` instead of `.search`:

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("server_to_connect_to")
imap.login(username, password)

status, messages = imap.select("INBOX",readonly=True)
imap.literal  = u'"Subject to be searched"'.encode('utf-8')
res, uid = imap.uid('SEARCH', 'CHARSET', 'UTF-8', 'SUBJECT')
messages = msg[0].decode('utf-8').split()

for uid in messages:
    res, msg = imap.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')
    #parsing logic
```

Comment: where is the first `msg` from?

Answer (score 0):

Using the search you could use a feach in the uid

````
```    
    EMAIL = 'your_email'
    PASSWORD = 'your_password'
    
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    imap.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    imap.select("INBOX", readonly=True)
    
    imap.literal = "Subjéct tô be searchéd".encode("utf-8")
    _, list_email_id = imap.search("utf-8", "SUBJECT")
    
    for email_id in list_email_id[0].split():
        _, data = imap.fetch(email_id, "(RFC822)")
        #email = MailMessage(data)
```
````

You can use imap_tools to instantiate data as imaplib result returns binary and need to use decoding. the MailMessage class of imap_tools does the handling and is easy to use