# Search utf-8 string with GMAIL imap X-GM-RAW

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-imap, imaplib

Seems

How to make GMAIL SEARCH with non-ascii strings

Some [comment from Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-mail-xoauth-tools/5B_lwWFYbDw), but can't grasp how to create it with Python and `imaplib`:

> Send non-ASCII data using literals:

```
. search charset utf-8 x-gm-raw {30}
+ go ahead
"живалов -йцукен"
* SEARCH 586
. OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of [Python IMAP search using a subject encoded with utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997928/python-imap-search-using-a-subject-encoded-with-utf-8) and after extensive research I have reached the same conclusion there: currently this is impossible to achieve with Python's [`imaplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) module, because the [`search`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search) method doesn't support IMAP literals (`{<number>}` strings used to denote the literals are quoted by `imaplib`). The same aplies to the [`uid`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.uid) method, so it can't be used to workaround the `search` limitation.

Note that in the past this functionality probably was implemented without using IMAP literals, as can be seen in the question [Python IMAP search using a subject encoded with iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640327/python-imap-search-using-a-subject-encoded-with-iso-8859-1).

Some hacking of `imaplib` is clearly required so `search` supports passing the search string as a literal, like in the raw IMAP interaction in your question. A possibility may be to implement it in the context of the [imapclient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) project which may be easier than contributing changes to the Python standard library.

Comment: What about imaplib2, I didn't check it yet?

Comment: From a cursory look at the source code of `imaplib2` it also appears to have the same limitations.

Comment: This is possible using `client.literal` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17612617/443900

Answer (score 1):

My [fork of the IMAPClient](https://bitbucket.org/john2x/imapclient) library adds a [`gm_search()`](https://bitbucket.org/john2x/imapclient/commits/cba69ca49fc0dc22392d19905d50ec79f77ea9d6) method which perform's Gmail's X-GM-RAW search query using IMAP literals.

Example:

```
imap_client.gm_search(u'subject:"ƒoo∫ar" has:attachment', charset='utf8') 
# The method encodes the unicode string internally. I'm debating with myself if that's a good idea or not.
```

I'm waiting for feedback from the author if it should be included in the main project.

Comment: Did you get this merged upstream?

Comment: Yeah I think this was merged upstream IIRC. It's been a while though so it might be in a different state now.